# When storing a component in state, it no longer re-renders when its props are changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a particular business case, I have a series of components that are laid out in a linear fashion, however the order of which may change. For example, we have a parent component:

```
export const Component = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const [nextComponent, setNextComponent] = useState(null);

    return (
        //... component code here
        {nextComponent}
    );
}
```

Inside the `Component` code would be buttons that can change which component is to come next:

```
onClick={() => setNextComponent(<SomeComponent data={data} setData={setData} />)}
```

If `data` changes by calling `setData` within `SomeComponent`, the component is not re-rendering with the new `data` prop value.

I understand this is something to do with the `SomeComponent` being stored in state, but can not understand why `data` does not update in `SomeComponent` - surely `data` is just a pointer to a memory location, and should therefore have the same value across the parent and child?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `data` prop is only updated for `SomeComponent` when the function `setNextComponent` is called as part of your `onClick` callback.

The "right way" to do this is to hold the data that matters to `SomeComponent` in its parent's state, then pass it down as part of a conditional render of that child.

```js
const ChildComponent = ({ data, setData }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <span>Current Data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</span>
    <input onChange={({target}) => setData(target.value)} placeholder="Enter New Data" />
  </React.Fragment>
);

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const CHILD_TYPES = { signIn: SomeComponent, signOut: OtherComponent };

  // keep track which component you want to be showing based on parent state
  const [activeComponentType, setActiveComponentType] = useState('signIn');

  // keep track of the data required for the child component(s)
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  // find and use the correct class for the current child type
  // (you could do this without an extra variable by using `React.createClass`)
  const ActiveComponentClass = CHILD_TYPES[activeComponentType];
  return (<ActiveComponentClass data={data} setData={setData} />);
}
```

Also, you should consider not storing components in state. It's bad practice and usually won't work the way you expect.